# Different Output for Test Between IntelliJ and Maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, junit, objectmapper

I have a simple check with ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString for a test to verify that no input have been changed without a developer having noticed it. It works fine but the issue is that the length diffs between JUnit and Maven.

I have tried the following things to correct it:

- Cleaned the cache of IntelliJ
- Verified that both of them run the same version of ObjectMapper (2.14.2)
- Removed all .m2 artifacts in case something was causing issue in there

Comment: A more probably explanation is that you're somehow reusing the instance of the ObjectMapper without noticing since IntelliJ and Maven's runners have different logic as to when they instantiate a test class. Can you share the relevant snippet?

Comment: what exactly do you mean with "JUnit and Maven"? Maven executes JUnit tests as well, so what is the other method you run JUnit tests?

Comment: @Mureinik Maybe? I have ran all of the tests as a suite in IntelliJ and that works fine but there could be something like that, I will do some testing

Comment: @cyberbrain With JUnit I mean in IntelliJ by pushing the button or through the 'Run All Tests' button when running from a module. Compared to 'mvn clean install'

Comment: Did you specify the character encoding in your tests? It would be helpful if you can provide a [mre] in your question and also add the different methods of running the test there.

Comment: @cyberbrain writeValueAsString doesn't have a char encoding though? I will see if I can get a stripped version working

Answer (score 0):

Finally found it! It was locale that was playing tricks on me, in normal JUnit it defaulted to 'EN' but in maven it was 'EN_US' so appended extra characters in multiple places.